# Counter Strike Global Offensive frame rate issues

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When I am playing CSGO I never used to lose frames, but ever since a few days ago, yes all the drivers and game is up to date, I started to lose frames going from 160+ fps drop down to 25-40 fps when I look or shoot at someone. Any ideas why? I tried to delete and redownload the game and it didnt work

Computer Specs

- Motherboard - MSI X99A SLI Plus
- GPU - Nvidia GeForce GTX 970
- RAM - 8 GB DDR4-2800 G.SKILL Ripjaws V
- CPU - Intel® Core™ i7 5820K Processor (6x 3.30GHz/15MB L3 Cache) - Intel Core™ i7 5820K
- Processor Cooling - Corsair Hydro Series H55 120mm Liquid CPU Cooler - Standard 120mm Fan
- Power Supply - 800 Watt - Standard 80 PLUS Bronze
- Hard Drive - 1 TB Hard Drive 32 MB CaCHE 7200 rpm
- OS - Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Check your power options and make sure you aren't in a power saving mode.

Comment: @TimmyJim im in high performance mode

Comment: Is it only happening with CSGO? Can you check processes running and performance while executing CSGO and while idleing at the desktop?

Comment: P.S. Frames are not linked to lag. Lag is related to ping which is your internet connection, fps to frame rate which is your hardware. Edited that for you ;) (https://media0.giphy.com/media/R6bDgXEXCLcIw/200_s.gif)

Comment: Make sure CSGO knows to use your Nvidia GPU and not the onboard intel graphics. I was in a similar situation  and that was my fix.

Comment: @Alex when im idleing on my desktop on at around 2-3% CPU usage on CSGO i jump around anywhere from 2-60% and have 57 out of 7.9 memory being used

Comment: @Adonalsium thats mainly for laptops, im using a desktop

Answer (score 1):

**Verify Game Files**

Clutching at straws here, but have you tried 'Verifying Integrity of Game Cache'? Not sure if this will help but worth a shot:

Steam article on how to do this:

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335

**Console Command**

Found this on a reddit thread:

> This is most likely your computer loading textures on the fly. There
>   is a config option to force preload all textures instead of loading on
>   the fly, cl_forcepreload 1. Try adding that to your config or just
>   enter it into the console.

**Another Possible Fix**

> If you open net_graph you will probably see a lot of choke the moment an enemy
>   gets close to you. Try to use the command 'rate 80000' if your playing
>   mm and if you play on 128 tick use 'rate 128000' and see if that
>   resolves the issue.

You may have to enter this command every time you play but at least at makes the game playable.

**Sound Drivers**

I know it sounds strange but the game may be having trouble loading the sounds in game, ensure that your sound drivers are all up to date

**External software**

If you are running any external software that affects sound or maybe software that captures gameplay, try playing the game without it and see if that helps.

**Summary**

This seems like an issue that will pop up for people for hundreds of different reason so my advice, if none of these work, is to just take a look around at different forums and articles, try all of the different fixes and hope for the best.

Hope I helped, good luck.

Comment: FPS drops will never be caused by internet connection problems as it has nothing to do. Laggy screen yes, but never FPS drops and he clearly says "*i started to lag going from 160+ fps drop down to 25-40 fps*"

Comment: You say 'Laggy screen', does that not mean that your fps has dropped? meaning it is an fps drop?

Comment: No, you can have lag caused by internet connection or fps drops

Comment: The word lag is related to your ping (ms) which is related to your internet connection. Your framerate is linked to your hardware. Losing frames is what you are calling "lag" in this instance.

Comment: I mean if this is really that much of a problem I'll take it out of my answer but connection to the matchmaking server has been linked to the lag described.

Comment: If he specifically saw his framerate go down, it's not linked to his internet 100% sure (whatever the game). If his ping went up would have been characteristic of a server/client handling issue.

Comment: Edited answer so it no longer includes ties to a bad internet connection, as it has been pointed out that this is not the issue.

Comment: it seems like it starts to drop frames when i start clicking "wasd" keys for moving around or whenever i click to shoot